# Nested reference with custom formula for conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to set conditional formatting rules based on dates such that a date entered into one tab in the Google Sheets is compared with a date in another tab, which is in turn selected based on a value in another tab. The application here is to have dates turn red when they fall outside a date range that is chosen based on a cycle number. For example, if cycle 005 runs from 05/08/17 to 05/21/17 and the date entered in a range of cells (there is a "from" and "to" column) is 05/07/17 (before the earliest date in the cycle) or 05/20/18 (after the latest date in the cycle) then the cell will turn red.

I have one tab (called `lookup_table`) that has cycle numbers and their corresponding "from" and "to" dates, another tab (called `review`) where the cycle number for a given data set is entered (into cell B2), and a third `data` tab where "from" and "to" dates are entered. The formula needs to reference "from" and "to" dates in the `lookup_table` tab based on the cycle number in the `review` tab to conditionally format the dates entered into the `data` tab.

I have found some similar questions about conditional formatting but nothing involving putting together a "nested" function comparing dates after referencing them based on another value.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting with a formula can use nested logic, because the formula can be nested, `=if(...if(...vlookup(...)))` and so on. When a reference to another sheet is made in a conditional formatting formula, it should be wrapped as `indirect`, i.e., `review!B2` should be replaced by `indirect("review!B2")`.

Step 1: get cycle number, `review!B2`

Step 2: Look up "from" date, `=vlookup(review!B2, lookup_table!A:C, 2, False)`. The assumption here is that in the lookup table, cycle numbers are in column A and From dates are in column B. (2nd column of the range)

Step 3: Add conditional formatting rule, "Date is before"... "exact date" and enter the formula from step 2 in "exact date", wrapping cross-sheet references in `indirect as mentioned earlier.

```
=vlookup(indirect("review!B2"), indirect("lookup_table!A:C"), 2, False)`
```

Step 4: Look up "to" data, `=vlookup(review!B2, lookup_table!A:C, 3, False)`. The assumption here is that in the lookup table, cycle numbers are in column A and From dates are in column C. (3rd column of the range)

Step 5: Add conditional formatting rule, "Date is after"... "exact date" and enter the formula from step 4 in "exact date", wrapping cross-sheet references in `indirect as mentioned earlier.

```
=vlookup(indirect("review!B2"), indirect("lookup_table!A:C"), 3, False)`
```

Comment: Crazy Ivan, it works!!! The 'vlookup()' function is definitely what I was missing. I guess nesting was not necessary here. The only thing I had to change was where the quote marks end: `=vlookup(indirect("review"!B2), indirect("lookup_table"!A:C), 3, False)` Everything else is just what I needed. Thanks so much for the prompt reply and very clear breakdown and presentation of my problem!