# I am trying to use vlookup as a conditional formatting formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet that has a roster of people. I want the sheet to automatically color code people on the roster tab that are also present on a second tab that lists people who have dietary restrictions. I thought that conditional formatting would be the way to go, but I can't get the formula to work. I also can seem to get the conditional formatting formula to be relative based on the row. This is the formula that I have so far. A5 is the first cell that contains the person's ID number. The ID numbers are listed in column A on the "Dietary Restrictions" sheet.

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A5,'Ghost Students'!A:H,1,FALSE)))
```

Comment: Select your range of values starting from `A5` and use: `=COUNTIF('Dietary Restrictions'!A:A,$A5)`. Does that work for you? Also, this works for Excel, which is not the same as GS, so I don't know if we can apply the same rule to GS.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I am using Google Sheets and it did not work.

Comment: This question is similar.  The key is to use COUNTIF against the range in the other tab, but you must use iNDIRECT referencing (or named ranges?) when referring to another tab in a conditional formatting rule.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908426/how-to-conditionally-format-a-cell-in-google-sheets-if-its-content-is-present     Or see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966835/nested-reference-with-custom-formula-for-conditional-formatting                   Does this help?

Comment: If not, please share a sample of your sheet, with dummy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to highlight values from `A5:A` in one sheet (let's call it `Roster`) if they are present in column `A` from another sheet (`Dietary restrictions`).

Since conditional formatting formulas cannot reference other sheets, you have to use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) in order to reference that.

You can then use [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) to check if the value is present.

Your formula could be like this:

```
=MATCH($A5,INDIRECT("'Dietary restrictions'!A2:A"),0)
```

#### Output:

> Sheet `Roster`:

[image]

> Sheet `Dietary restrictions`:

[image]

Comment: Almost perfect! I need the entire row to be formatted, but this formula will only apply the conditional formatting to data in column A.

Comment: @KelseyJimerson In that case, you just need to add the `$` parameter to `A5` in the custom formula, and change the range to apply to include all columns (`A5:Z`). Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yep! Adding the $ parameter to my search key did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about making vlookup formula grabbing data about dietary conditions from another sheet, and then putting conditional formatting.
You can hide information about dietary conditions if you want and apply conditional formatting based on hidden column:

[image]

Just tried. Conditional formatting works with hidden columns too.

Comment: I thoughe about that first. But unfortunately, I cannot add columns to the main sheet. It feeds into a larger network data sheet that I cannot edit, and any additional columns throw those formulas off.